# Почему при записи значений из С++ в текстовый документ нецелые числа пишутся с запятой, а не с точкой?

Tags: c++

Почему при записи значений из С++ в текстовый документ нецелые числа пишутся с запятой, а не с точкой, хотя эта же программа в командном окне выводит их с точкой? И как это исправить?

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Comment: скорее всего причина в русской локали, в которой принято разделять запятой. вероятнее всего у Вас в коде есть такая строчка `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");`

Comment: всегда с++ записывала с запятой. Если вы потом используете эти данные в екселе то там можно заменить представления чисел через запятую в настройках

Comment: @Alexey Nikolaev, спасибо, так и есть))